# Proof that a function terminates

Tags: algorithm

`if x is even , then F(x)=x/2 else F(x) = F(F(3x+1))` . Prove that `F(x)` terminates for all integers `x`.

Can anyone help me with this . I am studying "Fundamentals of computer algorithms". I can't understand how to proceed with this.

Comment: You omitted the hint: "consider integers of the form (2i+1)2^k - 1 and use induction". Really, this is a math question and you'd be better off asking on math.stackexchange.com, but I expect you'll be asked to show where you're stuck there.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I'm not sure it was a good idea -- without math formatting, it's quite hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a hint in the book that you omitted: "consider integers of the form (2i+1)2^k - 1 and use induction". Without the hint, it's a rather hard question.

So, using the hint, note that you can write any number as `(2i+1)2^k - 1` for some i and k. You can observe that `k` is the number of 1s at the bottom of the number in base 2.

Using this, you can prove that F terminates by induction on `k`. The base case of k=0 is immediate, since `(2i+1)2^0 - 1` is even.

Otherwise, when k>0, `(2i+1)2^k - 1` is odd. Then

```
  F((2i+1)2^k - 1)
= F(F(3((2i+1)2^k - 1)+1))
= F(F(3(2i+1)2^k-2))
= F((3(2i+1)2^k-2)/2) (since k>0)
= F(((6i+3)2^k-2)/2)
= F((2(3i+1)+1)2^{k-1}-1)
```

By the induction hypothesis, `F((2(3i+1)+1)2^{k-1}-1)` terminates since it has a smaller `k`, and we're done.

Comment: Interesting question and proof technique!  The function here is basically the same as that in the Collatz conjecture, and this shows that starting with any number, the Collatz conjecture procedure will reach some even integer.  If the technique could be extended to show that it reached some *power of two* then it would be solved (so I guess that's the really hard part... :-)

Comment: yeah, Collatz conjecture is still unproven, and for k=0 we get 2i->i on the next step, with little idea of how to proceed

Comment: EDIT: ok just noticed that the function in question terminates immediately on even numbers

Comment: Yes that's it !!! Thanks a lot!!! I got stuck by looking at the hint itself and didn't know how to proceed. So,I decided to ignore the hint and try on my own.Really was a hard task.Can you answer one more question?How did they come to the conclusion that to prove this question , the integer has to be written in the format (2i+1)2^k-1?I mean,there has to be some reason for that.Any ideas??

Comment: @Reckoner Perhaps by looking at examples, and noting the fact that the number of trailing 1's in the binary representation of the number decreases by 1 each time. The (2i+1)2^k-1 representation probably came later as a way to formalise the idea of counting the trailing 1's.

Comment: @Paul Hankin Need to do some research on that.Once again,thanks a lot,really helped me!!!